# Kubernetes nginx ingress: set client_max_body_size for one subdomain only

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

How do I set the `client_max_body_size` parameter for a single subdomain? I have a server that will accept file uploads up to 5TB. All the examples I've looked at show you how to set it globally. I have multiple rules in my ingress.yaml, I don't want every single rule to inherit the `client_max_body_size` parameter, only the file upload server should.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: homepage
          servicePort: 80
  - host: storage.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: storage
          servicePort: 80
```

In the above ingress.yaml, I want to set `client_max_body_size` for the `storage` service only, which is located at the host `storage.example.com`.

Answer (score 4):

In more recent versions of `ingress-nginx`, there is a dedicated annotation for the ingress resource called [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size):

```yaml
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 5tb
```

If you use the `configuration-snippet` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904367/2866660), it would currently result in an error like:

```
[emerg] 551#551: "client_max_body_size" directive is duplicate in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg123:321
nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive is duplicate in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg123:321
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg123 test failed
```

Answer (score 3):

Because I don't see `client-max-body-size` on the [list of annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/), that leads me to believe you'll have to use the [custom-config-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) to include the `client_max_body_size 5tb;` for that Ingress:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      client_max_body_size 5tb;
```

However, given that you said that you only want it for `storage.example.com`, you'll need to split the Ingress config for `storage.example.com` out into its own Ingress resource, since (AFAIK) the annotations are applied to every `host:` record in the Ingress resource.

Comment: Yeah I figured I would need a separate Ingress resource. For the record, the annotation exists, but it's named differently for some reason. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size

Answer (score 0):

The annotation is `nginx.org/client-max-body-size` nowadays

```yaml
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.org/client-max-body-sizee: 5tb
```

Source: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#summary-of-annotations